# Destination MAC address field of Wifi client

Tags: wifi, broadcast, mac-address

Say Wifi client (MAC ID : CLI) is connected to access point (MAC ID : AP). Client wants to send data to server (MAC ID : SER).
Then Client's Outgoing wifi packet has following MAC address fields.
To DS: 1
From DS: 0
Receiver address : MAC address of access point, which is AP (technicality it is called as BSSID)
Transmitter address : MAC address of client, which is CLI in this case
Destination address : MAC address of destination, which is SER in this case.

Client knows access point MAC ID while wifi connection establishment phase.
How does client fills server MAC? how client knows about server MAC?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the CLI have the IP adresse of the server.

IF the two device are in the same network read this

CLI sends a broadcast request to all devices in the broadcast domain to get the mac address of the device having the configured IP adresse .

the SERVER responds to CLI by sending his own mac address .

The CLI fill destination MAC address and send to AP ,AP will redirect it to SERVER according ti Destination Mac addresse

to avoid this for every communication , CLI will save this mac adresse in the mac-address-table

IF the two devices CLI and SERVER are not in the same network you should learn about **`routing`**

Comment: Thanx hacene. To summarize(got after some googling), in same network, ARP protocol(as you explained) is used. Where as if server is not in same network, Client sends IP header as (Src : IP of Client, Dst  : IP of Server) and MAC header as (Src : MAC of Client, Dst : MAC of DEFAULT GATE WAY). So packet keep going through network routers until it reaches the destination IP. During this process IP address list(L3 Layer) is not changed where as MAC address(L2 Layer) list keeps changing.